# getting NODE_OPTION not recognised error while using storybook

Tags: react-native, storybook

I am trying to run storybook using in a react-native application but when I use command yarn storybook, I am getting this error.

```
$ yarn sb-server
yarn run v1.22.19
$ NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider yarn storybook-server
'NODE_OPTIONS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

it would be very helpful if some can provide solution.
thanks!

Comment: try this `(export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && yarn storybook-server)`  this may work for you

Comment: are you running on windows?